# TouchableWithoutFeedback onFocus doesn't fire

Tags: react-native

I've built this component according to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback to get a component class that changes style upon focus. I've tried this method but the onFocus isn't invoked when I'm pressing the component. I'm working with android & expo though I think it's not the cause.

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onFocus={()=>this.setState({shouldFocus: true})}>
  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>

    <View style={[styles.subContainerStyle, {flex:1}]}>
      <Text style={[styles.propertyStyle, {
        color: this.state.shouldFocus ? '#50AFAD' : 'black',
        fontWeight: this.state.shouldFocus ? 'bold' : null}]}> LEFT </Text>
    </View>

    <View style={[styles.subContainerStyle, {flex: 2}]}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textValueStyle} placeholder={"RIGHT"}/>
      </View>
    </View>

  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: When you add an onPress to the TouchableWithoutFeedback, is that one triggered correctly?

Comment: Better if you use `onPressIn`.

Comment: On Press works fine. I want to create several instances of this class (fields of a form) and have just one that changes its style when focused.